# Single shared queue worker in Laravel multi-tenant app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, architecture, queue

I'm building a multi-tenant Laravel application (on Laravel 5.3) that allows each tenant to have its own set of configurations for any supported Laravel settings. This is currently achieved by overriding the default Laravel `Application` with my own implementation that provides a custom configuration loader (overrides the default `Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration`). The application detects the current tenant from the environment (either PHP's `$_ENV` or the `.env` file) on bootstrap and then loads the appropriate configuration files for the detected tenant.

The above approach works great for both the HTTP and Console kernels where each request/command has a limited life-cycle but I'm not sure how to approach the queue worker. I would like to have a single queue worker for all the tenants and I've already implemented a custom queue connector to add additional metadata when a queue job is scheduled, to make it possible to identify the tenant when the worker receives it.

The part on which I'm looking for your help is how to run each queue job in an isolated environment which I can bootstrap with my custom configuration.

A few possible solutions that I see would be:

- to run a custom queue worker that runs as a daemon and gets the job from the queue, but executes the job in a separate PHP process (created via `exec()`); once the job is executed, the worker gathers the results (status, exceptions, etc.) and finishes the job in the parent process (e.g. deletes the job, etc.)
- similar to the above, but run the job in a separate PHP thread instead of a separate process using `RunKit Sandbox`
- implement a solution that "reboots" the application once a queue job has been received (e.g. reloads configurations for the current tenant, resets any resolved dependencies, etc.)

What's important is that I'd like for this multi-tenant job execution to be transparent for the job itself so that jobs that are not designed to run in a multi-tenant environment (e.g. jobs from third party packages like Laravel Scout) can be handled without any modification.

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We have pretty much the same situation. Here is our approach:

### Service Provider

We have a ServiceProvider called `BootTenantServiceProvider` that bootstraps a tenant in a normal HTTP/Console request. It expects an environment variable to exist called `TENANT_ID`. With that, it will load all the appropriate configs and setup a specific tenant.

### Trait with __sleep() and __wakeup()

We have a `BootsTenant` trait that we will use in our queue jobs, it looks like this:

```
trait BootsTenant
{
    protected $tenantId;

    /**
     * Prepare the instance for serialization.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function __sleep()
    {
        $this->tenantId = env('TENANT_ID');

        return array_keys(get_object_vars($this));
    }

    /**
     * Restore the ENV, and run the service provider
     */
    public function __wakeup()
    {
        // We need to set the TENANT_ID env, and also force the BootTenantServiceProvider again

        \Dotenv::makeMutable();
        \Dotenv::setEnvironmentVariable('TENANT_ID', this->tenantId);

        app()->register(BootTenantServiceProvider::class, [], true);
    }
}
```

Now we can write a queue job that uses this trait. When the job is serialized on the queue, the `__sleep()` method will store the tenantId locally. When it is unserialized the `__wakeup()` method will restore the environment variable and run the service provider.

### Queue jobs

Our queue jobs simply need to use this trait:

```
class MyJob implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue {
    use BootsTenant;

    protected $userId;

    public function __construct($userId)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // At this point the job has been unserialized from the queue,
        // the trait __wakeup() method has restored the TENANT_ID
        // and the service provider has set us all up!

        $user = User::find($this->userId);
        // Do something with $user
    }
}
```

### Conflict with SerializesModels

The `SerializesModels` trait that Laravel includes provides its own `__sleep` and `__wakeup` methods. I haven't quite figured out how to make both traits work together, or even if it's possible.

For now I make sure I never provide a full Eloquent model in the constructor. You can see in my example job above I only store IDs as class attributes, never full models. I have the `handle()` method fetch the models during the queue runtime. Then I don't need the `SerializesModels` trait at all.

### Use queue:listen instead of --daemon

You need to run your queue workers using `queue:listen` instead of `queue:work --daemon`. The former boots the framework for every queue job, the latter keeps the booted framework loaded in memory.

At least, you need to do this assuming your tenant boot process needs a fresh framework boot. If you are able to boot multiple tenants in succession, cleanly overwriting the configs for each, then you might be able to get away with `queue:work --daemon` just fine.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. 

I didn't realise that `queue:listen` is actually very close to what I need but my problem with using that is that I need to set the tenant very early in the boot process to be able to override all the configs and this means that I need to somehow set the tenant and then somehow run trough all the bootstrapping again in the Application.

I opted not to assign the tenant id in the command for the exact same reasons you outlined. Instead of a custom trait that sets the tenant, I used a custom queue connector that saves the tenant id in the metadata.

Comment: You're going to have a hard time with that then. The queue payload doesn't get unserialized until after the framework is fully booted. I'd recommend revisiting your tenant boot process, figure out how to make it work after the framework has already booted.

Comment: I know :) Unfortunately I think I'll probably end up needing to run the actual job in a separate thread/process that's created by a daemonized queue worker as that would allow complete control over bootstrapping a new app with the correct configs.

I hoped that maybe there's a clever solution to somehow reboot an already instantiated application once I set a tenant but I think that will most likely not be as easy as I hoped.

Comment: What's very important for me is for this solution to be completely transparent for queue jobs created by third-party libraries so I need implement this in such a way that for them this runs the same way as a single-tenant app.

I'll mark your answer as accepted as it's a very good solution for others looking for similar implementations.

Thank your for your help with this.

Comment: Glad I could help, partially anyway. I'm curious though, if a queue job is created by a third-party, how would you know which tenant it belongs to?

Comment: I set the tenant as a property in the Application class so the queue connector can access it. The third-party library simply dispatches a queue job as regular but the queue connector adds the tenant metadata extracted from `app()` when it pushes the job to the queue I'm basically using a custom `RedisMultiTenantConnector` that extends `Illuminate\Queue\Connectors\RedisConnector` and overrides the `createPayload()` method to inject the additional metadata.

Comment: @jszobody, I can't express how thankful I'm for your detailed answer. For me that was a bright light during my journey to implement something similar to your solution. At the end I mastered changing the wheels on running Laravel train. There was hurdles and issues all along the way, but I was able to use custom .env file per each Tenant. In my case I'm using AWS EFS to store Tenant DotEnv configs and serve the web calls from AutoScaled cluster. However I was limited by EC2 instance memory, when I run a listener per Tenant. Now I was able to use only one listener per any amount of Tenants. TY!

Answer (score 4):

To extend @jszobody his answer, see the [TenantAwareJob](https://github.com/hyn/multi-tenant/blob/1380789375bb3eb75dbb4f951a44ec1876e5b5ee/src/Queue/TenantAwareJob.php) trait build by multi-tenant Laravel package.

This does exactly what you want, before sleep encodes your tenant, when waking up it boots your tenant.

This trait also works with `SerializesModels`, so you can pass on your models.

**Update**

Since Laravel 6 this doesn't work anymore. The `SerializeModels` trait overides the `__serialize` and `__unserialize` [functions](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Queue/SerializesModels.php).

New method is to register a service provider and hook in to the queue. This way you can add payload data and bootup the tentant before processing. Example:

```
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->extend('queue', function (QueueManager $queue) {
            // Store tenant key and identifier on job payload when a tenant is identified.
            $queue->createPayloadUsing(function () {
                return ['tenant_id' => TenantManager::getInstance()->getTenant()->id];
            });

            // Resolve any tenant related meta data on job and allow resolving of tenant.
            $queue->before(function (JobProcessing $jobProcessing) {
                $tenantId = $jobProcessing->job->payload()['tenant_id'];
                TenantManager::getInstance()->setTenantById($tenantId);
            });

            return $queue;
        });
    }
```

Inspired by [laravel-multitenancy](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-multitenancy/blob/master/src/Actions/MakeQueueTenantAwareAction.php) and [tanancy queue driver](https://github.com/tenancy/identification-driver-queue)

Comment: Thank you man, i was searching for this exact Trait. It have been removed from the current version of Hyn. Works like a charm with my setup (single database for each tenant).